# I need help understanding backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I've tried for a while to understand what backbone.js' purpose is, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

What are the benefits of using backbone.js to render your views rather than a PHP framework such as Laravel or Symfony?

Is it meant to be used in conjunction with a server side framework, in a situation where the server sends backbone everything it needs from the database, and then users can make changes to database entries efficiently without loading, and when they are done, backbone sends the updated data to the server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://backbonetutorials.com/why-would-you-use-backbone/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone is a framework for developing rich single web-page applications. It gives you some simple tools to keep your Javascript code ordered. Backbone let's you decide how to best use this tools in order to make what you want.

When you use a framework like the ones you mention, every time the user moves from one page to another, he has to reload the whole page. With Backbone, the only thing that the user exchanges with the server are JSON objects to display, create or edit your information.

As you mention to be able to use Backbone you are going to need an API server running in the back. The server is the one in charge of managing the database if you need to use one. As I mention before, JSON objects are send from and to the server to edit the information in your database.

I am not much of a PHP expert but I believe that you could use those PHP framework if you can create a server API with them. I usually use Ruby on Rails as my back end server. But you can use any framework with a RESTful API.

Here are a couple of links you can check out if you want to learn more:

- [Developing Backbone.js Applications](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/)
- [Backbone Tutorials](http://backbonetutorials.com/)
- [Backbone main site](http://backbonejs.org/)
- [NetTuts Backbone articles](http://net.tutsplus.com/tag/backbone/)

Hope this helps!